# gnuplot window in QtabWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, gnuplot

I'm writing, as a learning project, a program in python3 with GUI in Qt5. My main window is a tabWidget and I would like to display in one of the tabs window with (interactive) plot generated in gnuplot.

Now, I see there is createWindowContainer method but I can't figure out how to use it. I also found out there is QtGnuplotWidget, but the only examples I found were in C. More so, I can't load it in python3 interpreter.

I can't figure out how to embed gnuplot window within Qt5 GUI. Any advice on how to procede, or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example program showing how to embed a gnuplot Qt widget in a c++ program is included in the gnuplot source distribution. You could either go directly to the git repository or start with a release tarball, both available from the project site on SourceForge. The source files for this example are

```
.../src/qtterminal/embed_example.cpp 
.../src/qtterminal/embed_example.h
```

The rules to build it are in `.../src/Makefile`  but are commented out.  You should be able to uncomment them and proceed from there.  Combining all this with python is something I can't help with.